# Help me create interweaving texture

Tags: patterns, texture

I'm trying to create interweaving Spiderman 3 movie inspired black costume texture as seen here   1:25-1:27   https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=85&v=h87zZ_0AneU

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

I'm trying to create high quality pattern wallpaper from this. I have created pattern with gradient and applied it with Cross weave script in photoshop but result is no way near to what I'm trying to achieve I need more organic look.

This is pattern that I have created [image: pattern]

Any tips how can I approach this task will be welcomed . Thank you.

Comment: There's a nice [Tutorial how to create a similar mesh for a microphone](https://greyscalegorilla.com/tutorials/model-a-microphone-with-a-wire-mesh-texture-in-cinema-4d/) in Cinema4D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use a shape which is filled with a gradient for this, you can also use photos of metal rings or pieces taken from sturdy iron chain.

You probably can make several versions and fade gradually from one version to another horizontally and vertically with gradient or more random layer mask to create some variety and liveness.

Another, much more complex way is to make it in 3D software. The benefit of 3D is the ability to make the appearance dependent on the viewing angle and light conditions. That creates infinitely variations with virtually zero extra work.

A quick and dirty way would be copy a piece of your second image to the clipboard and define it to be a pattern in Photoshop. I tried it and it worked. I could paint with the pattern stamp tool as large area as I wanted. Unfortunately this cannot be published, because I have no right to use the image. I'm quite sure that you also cannot publish, sell nor give it for free.

ADDED due the comment:

Variety with fading between different versions: Have at least two different versions which exactly fit geometrically, only the colors, lights and shadows are a little different. Put them to different layers. Insert  to the top layer fully white layer mask. Spray to the layer mask randomly black or add to there a gradient. Black makes to second layer visible. Grey = Partially transparent.

**Another way to get variety**: Add a layer filled with small random dots that makes slight random variations to light. Use blending mode=multiply. That makes nothing brighter, so dark areas stay dark.

Here's a fully synthetic attempt to create the pattern in 2D:

[image]

layer "Variationize" has a random pattern that attempts to make every piece a little different. Here's a snippet of it turned to fully visible. In use it's opacity is reduced and the blending mode = multiply.

[image]

The weaved pattern is painted with the Pattern stamp tool. The repeating pattern was made in Illustrator by using gradients. The 2 directional roundness was achieved by stacking 2 different linear gradients, the upper has blending mode = multiply. The following cartoon hopefully shows, how the final square that was copied to Photoshop's pattern definition, was costructed:

[image]

Comment: That's the problem with me I created this pattern with only one gradient and that's why I don't see any variety.  what do you mean by several versions should I make whole texture by hand? because I just used one gradient and preset did the rest job. can you give me more in depth look how can I approach it , because I didn't understand quite right what do you mean by fading several versions together.

Comment: I have thought about pattern stamp tool also but I don't want exact copy of it I'm just inspired to create my own texture "black interweaving organic" to have rights on it.

Comment: @Nodo there's added a little about "getting variety"

Comment: Update: https://imgur.com/a/EvbYo
I hand draw rounded ring shape and than defined pattern using it. I think its better than first one. can you post image as well to show me your example?

Comment: @Nodo Much better now! I added a little to the variations-story according your new attempt.

Comment: Oh I understand what you mean now . so it's basicaly add some sort slight contrast on background image and add variation with above layer I got it.I can even play with lightness in Cross weave preset while defining pattern , but it's not the point and i know its getting tedious already and thank you for your patience and effort I appreciate it , but what bothers me is that I still feel like objects are not connecting to each other as they should be they are not interweaving. I'm having problem with shape.

Comment: @Nodo I completed the story and removed all copied stuff from it. The connectedness problem is solvable and solved. The whole weaving problem was interesting, thanks for it.