# Weave Effect in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

How would I create a weave (woven) effect in the following image in Inkscape? Tks!

[image]

OK, I ended up doing it as below, by manually overlaying alternating pieces of the correct length. (I'm guessing that's probably the only way to do it?):

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: placing manually patches is an attempt. Your pattern is periodic so you can tile it. Here https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100356/help-me-create-interweaving-texture the very last snippet in my old answer hopefully gives the idea of the needed tile. The case was complex because the questioner needed gradient coloring. If you do not need it manual patching is ok, You can simply copy and place full rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if you already tried this, but it would be fairly quick.

1. Enable the grid and snap to grid.
2. With the Rectangle tool, draw one line of shapes like the example (below left). Group them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
3. Copy <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and Paste in Place <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, move into position, and repeat another once. Flip one of these pieces vertically
4. Select these two pieces, and Copy and Paste in place, and move into position. Repeat until you have 10 lines.
5. Select all the pieces and Group. Copy and Paste in Place
6. Rotate 90° clockwise

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Also try the Knot LPE in combination with the Pattern along Path LPE:

[image: weave pattern with Knot LPE and Pattern Along Path LPE]

This uses:

- a grid of duplicated and evenly spaced (arrange dialog) paths, combined to a single path
- a rectangle turned to a path

To create this from the two base parts, do the following:

1. Apply the Knot LPE to the grid (Path > Path effects > + > Knot)
2. Switch to node tool. Click on the small handle on one of the crossings to switch the crossing's direction. Move the handle to another crossing, repeat until all crossings are to your liking.
3. Copy the rectangle-turned-to-path to your clipboard.
4. Apply the Pattern along Path LPE to your grid.
5. Use the 'paste path' button in the PaP dialog to paste the rectangle.
6. Adjust the fill color
7. Adjust direction and width of the 'reeds' with the fields in the dialog / the handle on the canvas.

This is probably not faster than the method from Billy Kerr, because you cannot use copy-paste to speed up the process. However, this option will be more easily adjustable, if you plan to make changes to your pattern later.